# Springboot JPA - detached entity passed to persist

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am learning Springboot with my previous JPA knowledge. Currently trying to create a simple web app with MySQL DB. At first I created 2 tables `users` and `users_session_data`.

`users_session_data` has a `OneToOne` relation, meaning every user can have a session data at once. Currently I want to create a user, but it gives me the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.simpleapp.entities.EntityUsersSessionData
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.persist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:755)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:739)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy137.persist(Unknown Source)
    at com.simpleapp.core.AbstractFacade.createRecord(AbstractFacade.kt:100)
    at com.simpleapp.flows.FlowUsersSessions.create(FlowUsersSessions.kt:42)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at com.simpleapp.flows.FlowUsersSessions$$SpringCGLIB$$0.create(<generated>)
    at com.simpleapp.flows.FlowUsers.login(FlowUsers.kt:71)
    at com.simpleapp.controllers.restful.services.users.ServiceUsersLogin.getData(ServiceUsersLogin.kt:38)
    at com.simpleapp.controllers.restful.services.users.ServiceUsersLogin.getData(ServiceUsersLogin.kt:12)
    at com.simpleapp.core.restful.AbstractRestService.getResponse(AbstractRestService.kt:26)
    at com.simpleapp.controllers.restful.ControllerUsers.getUserLogin(ControllerUsers.kt:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at com.simpleapp.filters.AppSecurityFilter.doFilter(AppSecurityFilter.kt:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at com.simpleapp.filters.AppSecurityFilter.doFilter(AppSecurityFilter.kt:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

My classes are as follows:

`BaseEntity`:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class BaseEntity : java.io.Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
  open var id: Int? = null

  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = false)
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  open var status: DBEntryStatusTypeEnum = DBEntryStatusTypeEnum.ACTIVE

  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = Utils.JSON_DATE_FORMAT)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "CREATED_AT", nullable = false)
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  open var createdAt = Date()

  override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    if (this === other) return true
    if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

    other as BaseEntity
    if (id != other.id) return false
    if (status != other.status) return false
    return true
  }

  override fun hashCode(): Int {
    var result = id ?: 0
    result = 31 * result + (status.hashCode())
    return result
  }
}
```

`BaseUserEntity`:

```
@MappedSuperclass
open class BaseUserEntity : BaseEntity() {

  @Id
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
  @JsonIgnore
  @XmlTransient
  override var id: Int? = null

  @JsonIgnore
  @XmlTransient
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  open var users: EntityUsers? = null

}
```

`EntityUsers`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@XmlRootElement
class EntityUsers : BaseEntity() {

  @Column(name = "NICK", length = 255)
  var nick: String? = null

  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "NAME_SURNAME", nullable = false, length = 255)
  var nameSurname: String? = null

  @Column(name = "ABOUT", length = 300)
  var about: String? = null

  @Column(name = "BIRTHDAY")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  var birthday: Date? = null

  @Column(name = "LAST_LOGIN")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  var lastLogin = Date()

  @XmlTransient
  @JsonIgnore
  @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], mappedBy = "users", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  var usersSessionData: EntityUsersSessionData? = null

}
```

`EntityUsersSessionData`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_session_data")
@XmlRootElement
class EntityUsersSessionData : BaseUserEntity() {

  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "TOKEN", nullable = false, length = 255)
  var token: String? = null

}
```

`FlowUsers`:

```
@Component
class FlowUsers {

  @Autowired
  @org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy
  lateinit var daoFactory: DaoFactory

  @Autowired
  @org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy
  lateinit var flowUserSessions: FlowUsersSessions

  /**
   * Returns dao object of users.
   */
  fun getDao() = daoFactory.getDaoUsers()

  /**
   * Checks if user exists and if exists returns user, if not, creates user then returns.
   */
  fun login(data: RequestModelUserLogin, ipAddress: String?): EntityUsers? {
    // Get user from the token via Firebase.
    val userData = FirebaseClientAuth.getCredentialsForToken(data.token) ?: return null

    // Otherwise create the user.
    var user = EntityUsers().apply {
      avatar = userData.photoUrl
      nameSurname = userData.displayName
      birthday = null // This will be filled by user.
      email = if (userData.email.isNullOrEmpty()) data.email else userData.email
    }

    // attached new id to the mUser (by creating database row instance)
    user = getDao().createRecord(user)

    // creates session for the first time for user and attaches it to user
    user.usersSessionData = flowUserSessions.create(user)
    return getDao().updateRecord(user)
  }
}
```

`FlowUsersSessions`:

```
@Component
class FlowUsersSessions {

  @Autowired
  @org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy
  lateinit var daoFactory: DaoFactory

  @Autowired
  @org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy
  lateinit var flowUsers: FlowUsers

  /**
   * Returns the dao object of user sessions.
   */
  fun getDao() = daoFactory.getDaoUsersSessions()

  /**
   * Returns a session for the given token.
   */
  fun getByToken(token: String) = getDao().getByToken(token = token)

  /**
   * Creates a user session entity, right after creating the user.
   */
  fun create(user: EntityUsers): EntityUsersSessionData? {
    val record = EntityUsersSessionData().apply {
      id = user.id
      status = user.status
      createdAt = Date()
      token = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    }
    return getDao().createRecord(record)
  }
}
```

I tried to replace CascadeType.ALL to CascadeType.PERSIST and CascadeType.MERGE but didn't work.

Comment: Confusing to read as it seems you have BaseUserEntity extending BaseEntity, with both defining an ID - you may have a few problems with your entity model. That aside, your issue seems to be exactly what the error states: You are passing in a detached instance of EntityUsersSessionData. This is likely attached to a new  EntityUsers, and you have the usersSessionData relationship marked to cascade the persist operation - so you are essentially calling persist on the detached EntityUsersSessionData. You have to figure out what you want to do with those EntityUsersSessionData

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are persisting a new EntityUsers but have included existing (detached) EntityUsersSessionData in the user's usersSessionData and you have the mapping set to cascade the persist operation. This is the same as calling entityManager.persist(entityUsersSessionData) on the existing EntityUsersSessionData instance - since it already exists, JPA is required to throw an error.

You need to determine what you want to do with these EntityUsersSessionData instances; if you want to merge them in or not. Easiest solution is to just not put the cascade option on the mapping:

```
  @XmlTransient
  @JsonIgnore
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "users", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  var usersSessionData: EntityUsersSessionData? = null
```

Apply CascadeType options on mappings sparingly and only when needed as they have consequences to the application that aren't always noticed upfront.